# How to Incorporate logic in Gapps for client side handlers?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a server side Gapps system, but the UI responsiveness is terrible.
Now (unsuccessfully) trying to switch the basic UI handling to client side handlers.

I have discovered the object model (?) documentation for clientside handlers at:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_clienthandler

The first problem seems to be the limited capabilities in Google Script to define event handlers.
I can find no way to incorporate "if" logic in my client side event handler.

Second problem is the (apparent) in-ability to provide client side (java) global variables.
Is there any alternative to storing client side data other than as text in a label or textbox?

I must be missing some basic concept here as I can find no way to provide a real client side Java module to be available in my Gapps delivered page source.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  The UI for this application is quite complex.

PS - the application demands server side processing for several UI triggers.

Comment: I would like to refer you [this entry](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/creating-more-responsive-applications.html) in the google apps script developer blog. It treats a bid what you are sugesting maybe you can get some ideia out of it. Than again the use of client side hanlders to me is very limited indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Client handlers are meant to do trivial tasks such as notifying the user of some progress while all the hard work is done in server handlers. Please post some code of your attempt so that better suggestions can be offered.

Regarding your second question, I prefer to use CacheService to store variable across handlers. For objects, I convert them to JSON and store them using CacheService

Comment: But i want to do a non-trivial task client side.  It seems this is impossible to do in Gapps.  Here is a specific example:  I want client side access to mouse click location and then modify style attributes to re-position an image.

Comment: It may be possible using HTMLService, as you can use jQuery and jQuery UI. I'm still not sure how much Caja strips out and allows through. I converted my gadget from a UiApp gadget to an HTML Service because of the response time. IE8 does not support Caja, however, so gadgets for IE8 users need to be UiApp.

Answer (score 0):

I think client handlers maybe confusing, but they make sense. Perhaps think of the handlers as doing the logic for you already. Instead of writing if-then logic, the client handlers will do the work for you. For example, if you want verify that a user has entered in numbers, and make it possible for the user to submit data if the entry is numbers only, then there is a client handler for that. All you have to do is, for example, have a button activated if the entry is numbers.

As you have seen in the documentation, there are many handlers to handle many situations where if-then statements may have been used.

I will be learning the how to handle data storage over the next few days, but there are a few ways to store data like Script and User Properties, scriptDB, spreadsheetd or using JDBC. Here is the documentation referring to the above storage options (in addition to the cacheservice mentioned by Srik) So, I can't offer any expertise there. Try this link for documentation on data storage:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/script_user_properties

Sorry for the vague answer, but I hope that gives you a least a hint of the direction you need to go for creating the client handlers.